# Porque mi consulta devuelve signos de interrogación

Tags: sql-server, xml

Estoy obteniendo signos de interrogación como resultado de lectura de una columna a la cual estoy leyendo el xml

La consulta con la que estoy obteniendo los registros y en la cual obtengo en uno de ellos el signo de interrogación es la siguiente:

```
Select tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Titulo,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar3)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Prioridad,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar4)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Estado,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/int3)[1]', 'int') Asignado,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/int2)[1]', 'int') TipoSoporte,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/int5)[1]', 'int') ProblemaReal,
    Convert(numeric(15,2), tp_ColumnSet.value('(/float1)[1]', 'float')) HrsReales,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar10)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')  AsignadoSG,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/ntext2)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') Descripcion
From Content.dbo.UserData   
Where ListId = 'C4B4' and tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = 'TICKET DE PRUEBA'
```

El resultado de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Titulo        | Prioridad | Estado |  Asignado |  TipoSoporte | ProblemaReal |  HrsReales |  AsignadoSG  |                                                                      Descripcion  
+----+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| TICKET DE PRUEBA |  (3) Baja |Iniciada|   497     |      2       |     31       |    12.00   |   ????????   |  &lt;div class="ExternalClass9DB19E6929B74D6EB9D92825BBE42503"&gt;&lt;p&gt;​ESTA ES UNA PRUEBA&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;    
+------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Como pueden visualizar lo que devuelve la columna `AsignadoSG` son signos de interrogación `????????` cuando el campo XML contiene lo siguiente:

```
<float1>1.200000000000000e+001</float1>
<int2>2</int2>
<int3>497</int3>
<int5>31</int5>
<ntext2>&lt;div class="ExternalClass9DB19E6929B74D6EB9D92825BBE42503"&gt;&lt;p&gt;​ESTA ES UNA PRUEBA&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</ntext2>
<nvarchar1>TICKET DE PRUEBA</nvarchar1>
<nvarchar3>(3) Baja</nvarchar3>
<nvarchar4>Iniciada</nvarchar4>
<nvarchar10>쐘ﾯ虳䍵᮴됱볈违</nvarchar10>
```

Como se puede visualizar en el xml la etiqueta `<nvarchar10>` contiene caracteres extraños cosa que tampoco esta bien y que al momento de devolver la consulta me devuelve signos de interrogación.

Analizando un poco puedo creer que sea un problema de intercalación tipo `collate` pero no tengo mucho conocimiento en ellos, o si alguien tiene alguna otra hipótesis bienvenida sea.

Comment: ¿estás seguro que tiene almacenado el valor que muestras? ¿Qué te muestra si seleccionas toda la columna, no sus valores?

Comment: @jachguate a que te refieres con mostrar la columna y no su valor ?

Comment: a hacer solo `select tp_ColumnSet from Content.dbo.UserData`. Yo sospecho que allí ya hay almacenados `????`, no lo que tu crees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El XML con el que estás trabajando tiene, en el elemento `<nvarchar10>` caracteres [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), que ocupan más lugar que los caracteres [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) o [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

El segundo parámetro de `value` es el tipo al que SQL Server tiene que castear el resultado, y vos le estás diciendo que lo haga a `varchar(MAX)`. Sin embargo, como `varchar` [sólo soporta UTF-8 o UTF-16](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (a partir de SQL Server 2019 si la collation es UTF-8, soporta unicode también, pero me imagino que no es tu caso por el resultado que estás viendo), no puede procesar el contenido de tu XML.

La solucion es cambiar el segundo parámetro para que sea `nvarchar(MAX)` [que sí soporta Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Por lo que la consulta corregida quedaría:

```
Select tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Titulo,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar3)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Prioridad,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar4)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Estado,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/int3)[1]', 'int') Asignado,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/int2)[1]', 'int') TipoSoporte,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/int5)[1]', 'int') ProblemaReal,
    Convert(numeric(15,2), tp_ColumnSet.value('(/float1)[1]', 'float')) HrsReales,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar10)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)')  AsignadoSG,
    tp_ColumnSet.value('(/ntext2)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') Descripcion
From Content.dbo.UserData   
Where ListId = 'C4B4' and tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = 'TICKET DE PRUEBA'
```